# insert and select all data entity framework and SP

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a sp that inserts data in table. The table has pk_id, doc_id and other fields. After insert I want to get all records based on doc_id

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertTable]
    @doc_id int
    ,......
AS
BEGIN

// Insert
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
       (
            doc_id
           ,..........
       )
 VALUES
       (
            @doc_id
           ,.......
       )           

// Select all records based on doc_id 
select * from [dbo].[Table] where doc_id = @doc_id

END
```

After creating the Sp i updated my EF model with this SP. In my context.cs file i found that the return type is int, which makes sense if my SP was only insert.

I followed [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx) article to change the return type using complex types and funtion imports. but when i try to "Get column information" I get this "The selected SP or function return no columns"

I want something like [this](https://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/entity-framework-6-multiple-result-sets-with-stored-procedures) but instead of retuining two list in want 1st int and 2nd list.

what changes do i need to make in my code

here is how i am calling my sp in my controller

```
   List<Table> List = new List<Table>();

   using (Entities entities = new Entities())
       List = (entities.insertTable(1, ......)).ToList();

   var result = new { List = List != null ? List: new List<Table>()};
   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but this does not work. I get an error in line List = (entities.insertTable(1, ......)).ToList(); which i think is obvious since i get two resultsets

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: All stored procedures returns an integer to show whether the procedure was executed successfully or not. Hence the integer (1,0). But why do you want to combine different functions in an `Insert` procedure? Keep them separate and call the appropriate code.

Comment: I dont want to make two db calls if i can do this in one call. insert and display result

Answer (score 0):

You can call **Database.SqlQuery** on your dbcontext:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<DtoType>("insertTable @param1",
     new SqlParameter("param1", 1));
```

You just need to provide a DTO type for the result set. In this case for **Table**.